# Cannot start SQL Server Agent (Version 2014 enterprise core)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

The SQL Server Agent log file has the following information. I already set the firewall for inbound 1433.

> 2014-11-04 11:59:43 - ? [100] Microsoft SQLServerAgent version 12.0.2000.8 (X64 unicode retail build) : Process ID 6108
>
> 2014-11-04 11:59:43 - ? [495] The SQL Server Agent startup service account is ......
>
> 2014-11-04 11:59:43 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 0). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
>
> 2014-11-04 11:59:43 - ! [000] Unable to connect to server '(local)'; SQLServerAgent cannot start
>
> 2014-11-04 11:59:43 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 27, Registry information is corrupt or missing. Make sure the provider is installed and registered correctly. [SQLSTATE 08001]
>
> 2014-11-04 11:59:43 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 27, Client unable to establish connection [SQLSTATE 08001]
>
> 2014-11-04 11:59:43 - ! [165] ODBC Error: 0, A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [SQLSTATE 08001]
>
> 2014-11-04 11:59:43 - ! [382] Logon to server '(local)' failed (DisableAgentXPs)
>
> 2014-11-04 11:59:43 - ? [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normally)

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you using? The agent service isn't enabled on the Express edition if that's what you're using.

Comment: It's Enterprise core edition.